# Java, события в javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, события, handle

В документации Java и в книгах написано, что для наблюдения за событиями надо создать соответствующий класс и зарегистрировать его.
Как то так:

```
 btn.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
            }

        });
```

Но до того как я все это прочитал я создал и зарегистрировал метод и все было хорошо:

```
btn.setOnMouseClicked(this::clicked);

// и где то в классе
private void clicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

И еще в методе `Node#setOnMouseClicked`:

```
public final void setOnMouseClicked(EventHandler<? super MouseEvent> value)
```

По моему это означает передать в параметр объект типа `EventHandler<MouseEvent>`.

1) Если это так, почему передача метода в параметр не вызвало ошибку?
2) Какой вариант использовать и зачем создавать отдельный класс, если можно и методом обойтись?

Спасибо

Comment: В документации и книгах видимо написано так, чтобы компилировалось и работало начиная с javafx версии 1.2, в то время как функциональщину и подобный синтаксис (`this::clicked`) завезли только в java8.

Comment: @AndreyM Спасибо, но я так и не понял, как возможно передать функцию как параметр? Что означает `EventHandler<? super MouseEvent> value` в заголовке функции?

Comment: `EventHandler` означает, что метод ожидает объект, реализующий этот типизированный интерфейс, но в интерфейсе всего один метод, что позволило превратить его в `FunctionalInterface`.  Это, в свою очередь, позволяет использовать функциональный синтаксис, который по большей части является _синтаксическим сахаром_ (масло масляное) и под капотом JDK ваш код обрамляется в то же создание нового объекта (но на этот раз анонимного), но уже без вашего участия

Comment: Хотя я погорячился) Вышеописанное про создание нового объекта верно, если бы вы написали `btn.setOnMouseClicked( () -> {/*bla-bla*/ });`. В вашем же случае JDK неявно объявляет ваш класс как имплементирующий `EventHandler` интерфейс, а в качестве самой реализации выступает метод `clicked`. Но это всё мои домыслы, в деталях подкапотной жизни не разбираюсь)